# Unable to login through gateway jhipster 4.9.0 microservice architechture

Tags: java, microservices, jhipster, jhipster-registry

I've generated microservice application through jHipster 4.9.0.
My UAA server is running on port 9999 and gateway on 8080 these microservices are connected through jHipster registry. When I try to log in through the gateway **it's giving me 404 for /auth/login** although gateway has this endpoint in AuthResource.java file.
I have just generated these microservices and trying to log in but unfortunately, I'm unable to log in. Please guide me if there is something wrong I do not want to use the latest version of jHipster. JHipster registry version is 3.3. war download from github. It would be great if you can help me in any way. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Can you see both uaa and gateway apps in the JHipster registry dashboard?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou yes I can see both in the registry.

Comment: if you take in a look in the network tab of your dev tools in chrome, and check the contents of the 404...is it a regular springish 404 page or a string with "cannot GET /auth/login"?

Comment: @DavidSteiman yes it is regular 404 not string "cannot GET /auth/login"

Answer (score 0):

referring to your comment on my question you are getting "Cannot GET /auth/login", which is an answer from webpack-dev-server and not the spring application. That means that the dev server doesn't proxy your request to the backend at all.

You can fix this error by changing the file "webpack.dev.js", where you should see something like this

```
    proxy: [{
        context: [
            '/uaa',
            /* jhipster-needle-add-entity-to-webpack - JHipster will add entity api paths here */
            '/api',
            '/management',
            '/swagger-resources',
            '/v2/api-docs',
            '/h2-console',
            '/auth' // that one is probaly missing!!
        ],
        target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080',
        secure: false,
        headers: { host: 'localhost:9000' }
    }],
```

it looks like there is no '/auth' in your proxy list. Add it and restart `yarn start` to make it work.

Comment: Hi @David Steiman, webpack.dev.js file has /auth endpoint any other suggestions? but i've two entries of /auth.
context: [
                **'/auth'**,
                /* jhipster-needle-add-entity-to-webpack - JHipster will add entity api paths here */
                '/api',
                '/management',
                '/swagger-resources',
                '/v2/api-docs',
                '/h2-console',
               **'/auth'**
            ]
should I remove one???

Comment: should I remove one?
actually I've named the **uaa** server as **auth** while generating uaa, is this the problem? I'm using jhipster 4.9.0

Comment: yes the double **/auth** was the issue. actually I generated the uaa with project name **auth** that was conflicting with /auth endpoint. thank you for replying @David Steiman.